# Inconsistent child (non-root) url handling between localhost and remote server for react app deployed to Jetty

Tags: reactjs, jetty

I am confused by the following observation while working on a react app (a side project) that is deployed to Jetty as the ROOT webapp. The app is deployed to both localhost for testing and a remote server when released. The behavior for root url "/" is consistent between localhost and the remote server. However, when manually entering a child url (eg, '/about') on browser address bar, the localhost Jetty server is able to serve it  whereas the remote Jetty server gives 404 "not found" error page.

Initially the Jetty server versions were different between localhost and remote. I changed the remote Jetty version to the same as the localhost version, but the inconsistency still remains.

I sort of understand why the remote server gives 404 page based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually). However, what seems especially confusing is somehow it works on localhost. Why is localhost special in this case?

Comment: Collect a Jetty server dump for both, https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html  - it should help you identify the difference between the two servers from a Jetty point of view.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I didn't take the dumps and compare them. Instead, I copied my local jetty distribution, including my webapps, to the remote the server. The apps behave identically and the jetty servers seem have exactly the same configs (eg, logging, which was different before). However, still, the non-root url handling is different between local and remote. Because the two jetty instances are exactly the same, I am a little doubtful taking dump would be helpful. On the other hand, I don't know how I can debug next. :-(

Comment: If you are modifying content in your jetty-distribution, then you are not using it correctly.  Use the `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` concepts properly. - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html

Comment: I didn't find a definitive reference, but it looks like the localhost behavior is a Chrome's feature.